# Anbox : cannot click in installed apps

Tags: anbox

I have install some android applications from both Google Play Store and manually via terminal for my anbox. I can boot those games I installed, but I can't click anything in the games screen. Any solution?

i.e :
I installed Ragnarok and run the apps, but I can't click the "confirm" to enter my games (Similar issues happened on few different games)
[image: Ragnarok M Eternal Love]